# How to clear inputs when clicking again

Tags: next.js

I have some inputs that create when I click on Start button. When I click on the button again, inputs are not cleared and have previous
data. I want inputs clear. How can I have them cleared?

```
    for (let index = 0; index <= length; index++) {
        inputs.push(
            <input
                key={index}
                maxLength={1}
                type='text'
                className={`${style} bg-primaryBlue border-primaryBlue outline-primaryBlue'`}
                onLoad={e => (e.target.value = '')}
                onReset={e => (e.target.value = '')}
                onChange={event => evaluate(event, word.charAt(index))}
            />
        );
    }
```